# How can you remove dataframe rows by group that occur before a specified character entry in R?

Tags: r

For example, suppose you were trying to efficiently remove all rows within each idnumber group that occurs before the word "Go" like the following without using for loops.

```
idnumber<-c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
status<-c("Get", "Ready", "Go", "Get", "Ready", "Get", "Ready", "Go", "Drive", "Get", "Ready", "Get", "Ready", "Go", "Drive", "Turn")
df<-data.frame(idnumber, status)

   idnumber status
        1    Get 
        1  Ready
        1     Go
        2    Get
        2  Ready
        3    Get
        3  Ready
        3     Go
        3  Drive
        4    Get
        4  Ready
        5    Get
        5  Ready
        5     Go
        5  Drive
        5   Turn
```

Desired results:

```
   idnumber status
        1     Go
        3     Go
        3  Drive
        5     Go
        5  Drive
        5   Turn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write a function to select rows. If "Go" is present in the group we select rows from that line till end of the group, if it is not present we don't select any row.

```
custom_fun <- function(n) {
  inds <- n == "Go"
  if(any(inds)) which.max(inds):length(n) else 0
}
```

and apply it by group

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(idnumber) %>% slice(custom_fun(status))

#  idnumber status
#     <dbl> <fct> 
#1        1 Go    
#2        3 Go    
#3        3 Drive 
#4        5 Go    
#5        5 Drive 
#6        5 Turn
```